# Connection to MySQL DB with App Engine

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, mysql-python

I am following the MySQL tutorial for Google Cloud found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/cloud-sql/). I copied the code in main.py as it is but I am getting the following error:

`File "D:\BitBucket\Code\main.py", line 44, in get
    db = connect_to_cloudsql()
File "D:\BitBucket\Code\main.py", line 34, in connect_to_cloudsql
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user=CLOUDSQL_USER, passwd=CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 191, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
TypeError: connect() argument 2 must be string, not None`

I see that `connect_to_cloudsql()` needs to take two arguments but I cannot find anything in the documentation that points to what.

My app.yaml looks like this:

```
  # application: reliance-it
  # # application: reliance-test
  # module: default
  # version: 5
  # runtime: python27
  # api_version: 1
  # instance_class: F2
  # threadsafe: true
  # automatic_scaling:
  #   min_idle_instances: 0
  #   max_idle_instances: automatic
  #   min_pending_latency: 30ms
  #   max_pending_latency: automatic

  application: reliance-group
  module: default
  version: 1
  runtime: python27
  api_version: 1
  threadsafe: yes

  env_variables:
      CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME: reliance-group:us-central1:cash-flow
      CLOUDSQL_USER: root
      CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD: p_ROOTadmin$123

  libraries:
  - name: MySQLdb
    version: "latest"

  - name: webapp2
    version: latest
  - name: jinja2
    version: latest
  - name: pycrypto
    version: "2.6"
  - name: PIL
    version: latest

  inbound_services:
  - mail

  handlers:
  - url: /stylesheets
    static_dir: css
    mime_type: text/css
  - url: /scripts
    static_dir: js

  - url: /favicon\.ico
    static_files: css/images/favicon.ico
    upload: css/images/favicon.ico



  #========Default Handler=========
  - url: /.*
    script: main.application
```

Comment: What's your `app.yaml` look like? Make sure you add the corresponding env variables as described here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/cloud-sql/#setting-up

Comment: I have updated the original post to show my app.yaml content

Comment: It looks like the env variables are not set correctly. I'm not on Windows, so not entirely sure. Try quoting the values. You can check if they are set correctly in your code by simply logging them to your console after reading them. Also, please make sure to change your password.

Comment: Thx I'll try that. DW that's not my real password of course though thx for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the output of `CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME = os.environ.get('connection-name')` is `None`. Just replacing that with `CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME = 'connection-name'` and doing the same for `CLOUDSQL_USER` and `CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD` does the trick.  I hope that people find my answer helpful if they ever face the same problem.